# How to turn a list/tuple into a space separated string in python using a single line?

Tags: python, string, collections, formatting, string-formatting

I tried doing:

```
str = ""
"".join(map(str, items))
```

but it says str object is not callable. Is this doable using a single line?

Comment: " ".join(map(str, items))?

Comment: Don't re-assign `str` to anything, it's a built-in function as well as type in Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use string `join()` method.

List:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> " ".join(l)
'a b c'
>>>
```

Tuple:

```
>>> t = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> " ".join(t)
'a b c'
>>>
```

Non-string objects:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> " ".join([str(i) for i in l])
'1 2 3'
>>> " ".join(map(str, l))
'1 2 3'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `map` need function as first argument.

Your code

```
str = ""
"".join(map(str, items))
```

Make `str` function as `str` variable which has empty string.

Use other variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Your `map()` call isn't working because you overwrote the internal `str()` function. If you hadn't done that, this works:

```
In [25]: items = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "stuff"]

In [26]: "".join(map(str, items))
Out[26]: 'foobarbazquuxstuff'
```

Or, you could simply do:

```
In [27]: "".join(items)
Out[27]: 'foobarbazquuxstuff'
```

assuming `items` contains strings. If it contains `int`s, `float`s, etc., you'll need `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> items=[1, 'a', 2.3, (1, 2)]
>>> ' '.join(str(i) for i in items)
'1 a 2.3 (1, 2)'
```